# R: rescale labels

Tags: r, scale, axis, label

I have a plot in `R` with data on a range from `0-50` on the x axes.
If I use the default labeling, I get this tick labels: `0,10,20,30,40,50`
As I know that these values are in reality divided by two, I would like to rescale the labels to: `0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25`.
Where the label now says `10`, it should show 5 aso.

I tried different adjustments of:

```
axis(, at=c().. and ,labels())
```

but without any success.

Comment: Why not just do `plot(XData/2, Ydata, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provied in the first comment, this works:
Plotting the data as

```
plot(XData/2, Ydata, ...)
```

works very well.